# bootstrap 5 and navbar text color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am very new to coding, trying to design my own navbar using bootstrap.  I can change the buttons, the search bars, the background color etc....but for the life of me, cannot select the text color.  I feel like I have tried every class and id, still no go.  What am I missing?  I am not sure which selector to use in CSS in order to override the bootstrap.  And yes, my style sheet is after the bootstrap one, as the buttons are being changed.

My navbar is below

```
<!-- navbar below-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

form class
                    <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to to put !important in it like below code and see if that works for you. Let me know.

You can also specify it more using your existing class like
li.nav-item > a {color:red !important;}

```css
li a{color:red !important;}
```

```html
<!-- navbar below-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

form class
                    <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to stick with BS5 utility classes, you could select different colors via class names. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/colors/#colors
i.e.:

```
.text-primary
.text-secondary
.text-success
.text-danger
.text-warning
.text-info
.text-light
.text-dark
.text-body
.text-muted
.text-white
.text-black-50
.text-white-50

<!-- navbar below-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

              <div class="px-5 bg-dark text-light">form class</div>
                <form class="d-flex">
                <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```